# In Java, how to convert a String to JSON Object?

Tags: java, android

The string is like so:

```
[{"Id":287,"Name":"aaaaaaaa","ProjectType":"GP"}, ... snip ...]
```

This STRING is not JSON yet since it is a string even though it was served up as JSON.

I am trying to convert that to a structure that I can work with in my Java app.

Can somebody help me out here. The examples I've found so far didn't work out for me. Basically, I was hoping to be able to iterate over the Dictionaries that are within the List.

My latest attempt to convert the string into a json, was this:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json_string);
```

This, however, returned `null`.

Thank you.

Comment: post your full string which u want to convert in json object

Comment: Which JSONObject have you imported?

Comment: are sure that the string begins with square bracket ?

Comment: @JonathanGarcía that just means the object is an array, which is valid JSON AFAIK.

Comment: `new` either returns an object, throws an OutOfMemoryError, or is interrupted by an exception thrown by the object's constructor. So it should be impossible for 'data' to become null in the above code.

Comment: Then i believe that should use JSONArray, JSONObject of instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at using the Gson Lib - it's very good at handling this sort of thing. If you implement it using generics you can create a set of serializers which would let you import data very nicely from mobile APIs. If you want more info on example implementations let me know

Source:
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

documentation:
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 0):

To go along with the Gson answer, I would suggest [jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes). In my experience it's faster and just as easy to use.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
Map<String, Object> myMap = mapper.readValue(myJSONString, Map.class);
```

In your case, where the JSON is a list (I'm not sure if that's legal as the "root" element) you'd need to do `List<Map<String, Object>> myList = mapper.readValue(myJSONString, List.class);`

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse("[{\"Id\":287,\"Name\":\"aaaaaaaa\",\"ProjectType\":\"GP\"}]");
        if(json.isJsonArray()) {        
            for(JsonElement elem : json.getAsJsonArray()) {
                //elem.getAsJsonObject().get("Id")
            }
        } else if (json.isJsonObject()) {
            //json.getAsJsonObject()
        } //other else cases for JsonNull, ...
    }
```